# Getting crun error when running container using podman in RHEL 9

Tags: containers, redhat, podman, redhat-containers, rhel9

I am trying to run a container using podman in RHEL 9, getting below error, any guidance and suggestion?

```
[ahmad@rhel9-2 ~]$ podman run -d -it --name php-app -v /home/ahmad/app/:/app:Z -p 8080:80 docker.io/webdevops/php-apache
Trying to pull docker.io/webdevops/php-apache:latest...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob 30611fcc1b5e done
Copying blob 5bed26d33875 done
Copying blob f11b29a9c730 done
Copying blob 930bda195c84 done
Copying blob 78bf9a5ad49e done
Copying blob 4c8b85719399 done
Copying blob f70f19977fc5 done
Copying blob 5131985698ec done
Copying blob 65538e0c8933 done
Copying blob d43f884b2c0e done
Copying blob 20d592fa47f1 done
Copying blob d3f32720a7f3 done
Copying blob 2f8bf6213034 done
Copying blob 8356225c2f81 done
Copying config eff3c24c72 done
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
/usr/bin/crun: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/crun: undefined symbol: criu_feature_check
ERRO[0158] Removing container f7f815e200f4a97cc48e3f325f447eefdd250cb866edd228e70d5dba310d8775 from runtime after creation failed
Error: OCI runtime error: crun: /usr/bin/crun: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/crun: undefined symbol: criu_feature_check
```

Uninstalled and reinstalled @container-tools, didn't help.

Comment: mismatch between your version of crun and podman perhaps?

Comment: As a work-around you should be able to switch back to runc instead of using crun. For example, run "podman --runtime runc run -d  ..." or you can make the change permanent in the /usr/share/containers/containers.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's an error in `crun` [1]. You have to downgrade your `crun` by doing `sudo dnf install crun-1.4.5-2.el9_0.x86_64`.

[1] https://access.redhat.com/discussions/6988326